# Python code to extract table from pdf not working

Tags: python

I am trying to read a pdf and extract tables from pdf to  csv file using camelot.
But i am unable to read the table as it shows error-:

TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance

My code:

```
import ctypes
import PyPDF2
import tabula
import camelot
open("YP-brochure-draft_final_08_2019.pdf","rb")
reader=PyPDF2.PdfReader("YP-brochure-draft_final_08_2019.pdf")
print(len(reader.pages))
fileName = "YP-brochure-draft_final_08_2019.pdf"
# extract all the tables in the PDF fileclean
tables = camelot.read_pdf(fileName)
# number of tables extracted
print("Total tables extracted:", tables.n)
# print the first table as Pandas DataFrame
print(tables[0].df)
```

Link for pdf : https://drive.google.com/file/d/14ZmhS95aFfCMJPBELdzVXfuIHh2GxgB5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi sir, could you please share your PDF file?

Comment: Link to pdf : https://drive.google.com/file/d/14ZmhS95aFfCMJPBELdzVXfuIHh2GxgB5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here on the CSV files generated: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17gu15KhH_ITyVTmE6vGLw7ktZ8HTfsEe?usp=sharing

I didn't reproduced the error, anyways, that was my output when I ran this script:

```py
import PyPDF2
import camelot

filename = "YP-brochure-draft_final_08_2019.pdf"

open(filename,"rb")
reader=PyPDF2.PdfReader(filename)
tables = camelot.read_pdf(filename)
for i in range(tables.n):
    tables[i].df.to_csv(f'table-{i+1}.csv')
```

I used Python 3.10. Pay attention on Google Drive link above, I also uploaded the `requirements.txt` file with the libs that I used on my local virtual environment.